# how can I proper put user input in left side of the print because when I run a code the user input is first to show. btw I'm beginner

Tags: java, netbeans, printing, user-input

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    String w;
    
    System.out.print("here : ");
    w = s.nextLine();  
    System.out.println("here1 : " + w);
```

output:

```
    user input
    here : here1 : user input
```

expected output:

```
    here : user input
    here1 : user input
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
string w = s.nextString();
System.out.println("here : " + w);
string x = s.nextString();
System.out.println("here1 : " + x);
```

Comment: Your code won't compile. It's prudent to verify your code before posting.